# Jquery - using a queue to create a slideshow - delay and dequeue does not work

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am experimenting with creating a slider that fadesIn the next image. This is the code however I am having two problems. I have to manually start the "autoplay" queue for each image. Also, the delay does not work and the fade starts at the same time. The images are currently set one on top of the other with a display: hidden value.

```
       var options = { duration: 500, queue: "autoplay" }
       for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
        $("#feat_img_" + i).fadeIn(options);
        }

       $("#feat_img_0").delay(3000).dequeue("autoplay");
       $("#feat_img_1").delay(3000).dequeue("autoplay");
               //etc
```

Comment: Do you know that all your images have the same delay of 3s?

Comment: Yes. I did not know when the start would be from. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Select all elements that have id starting with feat_img_
$('[id^=feat_img_]')
    // Apply same fadeIn to all
    .fadeIn({duration: 500, queue: "autoplay"})
    .each( function (index) {
        // dequeue after 3s for 1st element, 6s for 2nd element, 9s, 12s...
        $(this).delay (3000 * (index +1), function (){ dequeue('autoplay');});
    })
```

Comment: Thanks looks good. I found a library that does what I was looking for called blueberry. It's still in beta. Will go back to work on this code.